# Nuxt vue router problem with context and params

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I have some problems with my nuxt applications first of all i cannot save params. I saving it like that:

```
    quiz(id: string) {
      this.$router.push({ path: '/playlists/quiz', params: { id } });
    },
```

And then when i want to read this params in route that i have been pushed

```
    e() {
      console.log(this.$route.params);
    },
```

It's returning an empty object `{}`

**PROBLEM WITH PARAMS SOLVED**

Second problem is that I have problem with using $route in asyncData. I wrote that:

```
  async asyncData({ $axios, $route }: any) {
    let res;
    try {
      console.log($route);
      res = await $axios
        .$get(`http://localhost:8080/quiz/questions/${$route.params?.id}`)
        .then((res: object) => {
          console.log(res);
          return res;
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res = '';
    }
    return { res };
  },
```

and then i have error
`Cannot find name '$route'`

Comment: how do you fix the first problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `route`, not `$route`:

```js
async asyncData({ $axios, route }: any) {
  console.log(route);
  ...
}
```

Despite the fact that Vue conventionally names prototype variables with `$`, and the fact that Nuxt prefixes the `context` `$axios` property that way, Nuxt doesn't do that with `route`.